# Как в JS создать событие по нажатию на radio button

Tags: javascript, html, radio

Как в js сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на любой `input type="radio"` переходило на следующий вопрос, то есть чтобы было аналогично нажатию кнопки "Далее" ( событие в js `next.addEventListener('click', function (event)` )?

Ссылка на [тест](http://mkozlov.com/test/test.html)

```js
var next = document.getElementById('next'),
  prev = document.getElementById('back'),
  progressBar = document.getElementById('progressBar'),
  progress = document.querySelector('.progress-bar span'),
  wizardSubmit = document.getElementById('wizardSubmit'),
  wizardPercent = document.getElementById('wizardPercent'),
  resultContainer = document.getElementById('result'),
  result = 0,
  ajaxLoader = document.querySelector('.ajax-loader'),
  resultValue = 0,
  progressWidth = 0,
  counter = 0,
  progressStepLength = 0,
  wizardSection = document.getElementsByClassName('wizard-section');

progressStepLength = Math.round(100 / (wizardSection.length - 1)); //set length of one step for progressbar and percent counter

progress.style.width = progressWidth; //style for progress bar (width = 0)

next.innerHTML = 'Начать тест!';

//click on next button
next.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var step = wizardSection[counter].getAttribute('data-step'); //get data-step attribute from current section

  if (step == counter) {
    wizardSection[counter].style.display = 'none'; //hide current section
    wizardSection[counter + 1].style.display = 'block'; //show next section
  }

  counter++;

  console.log(counter);
  progressWidth += progressStepLength;

  if (counter <= 1) {
    progressWidth = 0;
  }

  next.innerHTML = 'Далее';

  prev.style.display = 'block'; //show next  button

  progressBar.style.display = 'flex';

  progress.style.width = `${progressWidth}%`; //add width to progress bar
  wizardPercent.innerHTML = `${progressWidth}%`; //add percent step for percent counter

  if (counter >= wizardSection.length - 1) {
    next.style.display = 'none'; // hide next and prev buttons if it is the last step
    prev.style.display = 'none';

  }

  if (step == (wizardSection.length - 2)) {

    // Calculate common values all checkboxes and calculate the result
    var inputChecked = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked'), // get all checked radio buttons (it is not an array)
      inputCheckedArray = []; // set empty array

    for (i = 0; i < inputChecked.length; i++) {
      inputCheckedArray[i] = parseInt(inputChecked[i].value); // load values to array
    }

    resultValue = inputCheckedArray.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
      return previousValue + currentValue; // get sum of all elements from array
    })

    //result = Math.floor(resultValue / (wizardSection.length - 2)) + ' '; // set result value to markup

    result = resultValue / (wizardSection.length - 2)

    result = result.toFixed(1)

    resultContainer.value = result;

    progress.style.width = '100%';
    wizardPercent.innerHTML = '100%';

  }
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 'fast');

});


//click on previous button
back.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var step = wizardSection[counter].getAttribute('data-step');

  next.style.display = 'block'; // show next button even if last step was the lasts

  if (step == counter) {
    wizardSection[counter].style.display = 'none';
    wizardSection[counter - 1].style.display = 'block';
  }

  counter--;
  progressWidth -= progressStepLength;

  //set zero progress in first step of quiz, because in fact first step is start page
  if (counter <= 1) {
    progressWidth = 0;
  }

  prev.style.display = 'block';

  progress.style.width = `${progressWidth}%`;
  wizardPercent.innerHTML = `${progressWidth}%`;

  if (counter == 0) {
    prev.style.display = 'none';
    progressBar.style.display = 'none';
    next.innerHTML = 'Start!';
  } else {
    prev.style.display = 'block';
  }

});


//Submit form (use jQuery)

$(function() {
  var form = $('#wizardForm'),
    formMessages = $('#formMessages');

  $(form).submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    formData = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log('ajax ok ');
        },
        error: function(data) {
          console.log('ajax error ');
        }
      })
      .done(function(response) {
        $(formMessages).toggleClass('cuccess');
        $(formMessages).css('display', 'block');
        $(formMessages).text(response);
        $('#wizardForm input').val('');
        console.log(formData);
        console.log(result);
        document.location.href = 'http://mkozlov.com/thanks.html';
      })
      .fail(function(data) {
        $(formMessages).toggleClass('error');
        // $(formMessages).addClass('error');
        $(formMessages).css('display', 'block');
        $(formMessages).text('Упс! Сообщение не удалось отправить');
        console.log(formData);
      });
  });

  $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $(formMessages).css('display', 'block');
    $('#ajaxLoader').css('display', 'block');
    console.log('ajax-start');
  })

});
```

```css
/* ==========Base styles: opinionated defaults=========== */

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
}

input {
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: outset;
  border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form-block {
  text-align: center;
  width: 45%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
}

.form-block-info {
  text-align: center;
}

.result-text {
  text-align: center;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
}


/*============= Variables ================== */

 :root {
  --accent: #f10315;
  --accent2: #b1020f;
  --text: #333;
}


/*============= Author's custom styles================== */

.start-section {
  text-align: center;
}

.wizard-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: var(--text);
  box-shadow: 1px 6px 22px rgba(49, 49, 49, .2);
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.wizard ul {
  list-style: none
}


/*Wizard-form*/

.wizard-section h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.wizard input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.wizard input {
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.wizard-content-block {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
  /*display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;*/
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: distribute;
  align-content: space-around;
}

.answer-variants {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 45%;
  flex: 45%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(217, 216, 230, .55);
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 1.7px 5.8px 21px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
  border: 1px solid rgba(217, 216, 230, .55);
  padding: .8rem 1rem;
}

.wizard-content-block label {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.wizard-content-block label span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  min-width: 15px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.wizard-content-block label span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 60%;
  width: 60%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-55%) translateY(-48%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.wizard-content-block label span:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 12px rgba(49, 49, 49, .4);
}

.wizard-content-block label input[type=radio]:checked+span {
  border: 2px solid #f10315;
}

.wizard-content-block label input[type=radio]:checked+span:before {
  background-color: #f10315;
}

.ajax-loader {
  display: none;
  margin: 5px auto;
}

.wizard .wpcf7-not-valid-tip {
  margin: 5px auto;
}

.input-result {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 22px !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* PROGRESS LINE */

.progress-bar {
  display: none;
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px auto 40px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.progress-bar>span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: var(--accent);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, var(--accent), var(--accent2));
}

.wizard-percent {
  position: absolute;
  /*right: -20px;*/
  top: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: var(--accent);
  width: 100px;
}


/* BUTTONS */

.wizard button.button-back {
  display: none;
  color: #363636;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 13px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .13);
}

.wizard .actions {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.wizard .button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #f10315;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all.3s;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  ;
  line-height: 1.5;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 13px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .13);
}

.wizard .button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wizard .button:hover {
  background-color: #f10315;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 13px rgba(49, 49, 49, .3);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.final-section .submit-btn {
  width: auto;
}

.form-messages {
  display: none;
  color: var(--accent2);
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid var(--accent);
}

.cuccess {}

.error {
  border: 2px solid red;
}


/* ============= Helper classes=============== */

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}


/*
* Hide only visually, but have it available for screen readers:
*/

.visuallyhidden {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* 1 */
}


/*
* Hide visually and from screen readers, but maintain layout
*/

.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}


/* ====================MEDIA==================== */

@media (max-width: 992px) {}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .wizard-content-block {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .wizard .button {
    width: 48%;
  }
  .final-section .submit-btn {
    width: 100%;
  }
  input {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .wizard-wrapper {
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .form-block {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="wizard-wrapper">
    <form id="wizardForm" action="send.php">
      <div class="wizard">
        <div class="progress-bar" id="progressBar">
          <span style="width: 0px;">
            <span class="wizard-percent" id="wizardPercent">0%</span>
          </span>
        </div>

        <!-- Start section -->
        <section class="wizard-section start-section" data-step="0" style="display: block;">
          <h2>Тест: Рейтинг Невесты</h2>
          <p>Если честно и объективно оцените себя по 24 параметрам, то сможете оценить свои реальные шансы выйти за муж за достойного, обеспеченного мужчину</p>
          <div class="wizard-content-block">

          </div>
        </section>

        <!-- Quiz sections -->
        <section class="wizard-section" data-step="1" style="display: none;">
          <h3>Сколько вам лет?</h3>
          <div class="wizard-content-block">
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="10">
                <span></span>
                18 - 20 лет
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="9">
                <span></span>
                21 - 22 года
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="8">
                <span></span>
                23 - 24 года
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="7">
                <span></span>
                25 - 26 лет
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="6">
                <span></span>
                27 - 29 лет
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="5">
                <span></span>
                30 - 32 года
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="4">
                <span></span>
                33 - 35 лет
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="3">
                <span></span>
                36 - 39 лет
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="2">
                <span></span>
                40 - 45 лет
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="1">
                <span></span>
                старше 45 лет
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

        <section class="wizard-section" data-step="2" style="display: none;">
          <h3>Оцените свою внешность</h3>
          <div class="wizard-content-block">
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="face" value="10">
                <span></span>
                Мисс Вселенная
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="face" value="9">
                <span></span>
                Топ модель Западного уровня
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="face" value="8">
                <span></span>
                Топ модель России
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="face" value="7">
                <span></span>
                Красивая
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="face" value="6">
                <span></span>
                Симпатичная
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="face" value="5">
                <span></span>
                Миловидная
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="face" value="4">
                <span></span>
                Неприметная
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="face" value="3">
                <span></span>
                Легкие недостатки
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="face" value="2">
                <span></span>
                Заметные недостатки
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="face" value="1">
                <span></span>
                Зато умная
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Result sections -->
        <section class="wizard-section final-section" data-step="25" style="display: none;">
          <div class="wizard-content-block">
            <h3 class="text-center result-text">Ваши рейтинг невесты:
              <input type="text" class="input-result text-center" id="result" name="result" value=""></h3>
            <h3 class="text-center form-info">Хотите узнать, что эта цифра значит и как повысить свои шансы выйти удачно замуж? </h3>
            <div class="form-block">
              <div class="form-group">
                <p class="text-center form-block-info">Регистрируйтесь на бесплатный вебинар, на котором вы узнаете все ответы.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="Ваше имя" id="name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="tel" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Номер телефона" id="phone">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Ваш e-mail" id="email" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="button submit-btn" id="wizardSubmit">Принять участие</button>
              </div>
              <div class="form-messages" id="formMessages">
                <div class="ajax-loader" id="ajaxLoader">
                  <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.0" width="64px" height="64px" viewBox="0 0 128 128" xml:space="preserve">
                    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#FFFFFF" />
                    <g>
                      <circle cx="16" cy="64" r="16" fill="#fdba00" fill-opacity="1" />
                      <circle cx="16" cy="64" r="14.344" fill="#fdba00" fill-opacity="1" transform="rotate(45 64 64)" />
                      <circle cx="16" cy="64" r="12.531" fill="#fdba00" fill-opacity="1" transform="rotate(90 64 64)" />
                      <circle cx="16" cy="64" r="10.75" fill="#fdba00" fill-opacity="1" transform="rotate(135 64 64)" />
                      <circle cx="16" cy="64" r="10.063" fill="#fdba00" fill-opacity="1" transform="rotate(180 64 64)" />
                      <circle cx="16" cy="64" r="8.063" fill="#fdba00" fill-opacity="1" transform="rotate(225 64 64)" />
                      <circle cx="16" cy="64" r="6.438" fill="#fdba00" fill-opacity="1" transform="rotate(270 64 64)" />
                      <circle cx="16" cy="64" r="5.375" fill="#fdba00" fill-opacity="1" transform="rotate(315 64 64)" />
                      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 64 64;315 64 64;270 64 64;225 64 64;180 64 64;135 64 64;90 64 64;45 64 64"
                        calcMode="discrete" dur="720ms" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform>
                    </g>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

        <!-- Step buttons -->
        <div class="actions">
          <button class="button button-back" href="#progressBar" id="back">Назад</button>
          <button class="button button-next" href="#progressBar" id="next">Далее</button>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="response display-none"></div>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм такой:

```
// Назначаем обработчик форме
$(form).on('change', function(ev) {
  // Если объект срабатывания - это "radiobutton", тогда...
  if (ev.target.tagName == 'INPUT' && ev.target.getAttribute('type') == 'radio') {
    // Создаём событие "click" и запускаем его, применительно к элементу "next"
    next.dispatchEvent(new Event('click', {
      bubbles: true
    }));
  }
});
```

Рабочий пример:

```js
var next = document.getElementById('next'),
  prev = document.getElementById('back'),
  progressBar = document.getElementById('progressBar'),
  progress = document.querySelector('.progress-bar span'),
  wizardSubmit = document.getElementById('wizardSubmit'),
  wizardPercent = document.getElementById('wizardPercent'),
  resultContainer = document.getElementById('result'),
  result = 0,
  ajaxLoader = document.querySelector('.ajax-loader'),
  resultValue = 0,
  progressWidth = 0,
  counter = 0,
  progressStepLength = 0,
  wizardSection = document.getElementsByClassName('wizard-section');

progressStepLength = Math.round(100 / (wizardSection.length - 1)); //set length of one step for progressbar and percent counter

progress.style.width = progressWidth; //style for progress bar (width = 0)

next.innerHTML = 'Начать тест!';

//click on next button
next.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var step = wizardSection[counter].getAttribute('data-step'); //get data-step attribute from current section

  if (step == counter) {
    wizardSection[counter].style.display = 'none'; //hide current section
    wizardSection[counter + 1].style.display = 'block'; //show next section
  }

  counter++;

  console.log(counter);
  progressWidth += progressStepLength;

  if (counter <= 1) {
    progressWidth = 0;
  }

  next.innerHTML = 'Далее';

  prev.style.display = 'block'; //show next  button

  progressBar.style.display = 'flex';

  progress.style.width = `${progressWidth}%`; //add width to progress bar
  wizardPercent.innerHTML = `${progressWidth}%`; //add percent step for percent counter

  if (counter >= wizardSection.length - 1) {
    next.style.display = 'none'; // hide next and prev buttons if it is the last step
    prev.style.display = 'none';

  }

  if (step == (wizardSection.length - 2)) {

    // Calculate common values all checkboxes and calculate the result
    var inputChecked = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked'), // get all checked radio buttons (it is not an array)
      inputCheckedArray = []; // set empty array

    for (i = 0; i < inputChecked.length; i++) {
      inputCheckedArray[i] = parseInt(inputChecked[i].value); // load values to array
    }

    resultValue = inputCheckedArray.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
      return previousValue + currentValue; // get sum of all elements from array
    })

    //result = Math.floor(resultValue / (wizardSection.length - 2)) + ' '; // set result value to markup

    result = resultValue / (wizardSection.length - 2)

    result = result.toFixed(1)

    resultContainer.value = result;

    progress.style.width = '100%';
    wizardPercent.innerHTML = '100%';

  }
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 'fast');

});


//click on previous button
back.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var step = wizardSection[counter].getAttribute('data-step');

  next.style.display = 'block'; // show next button even if last step was the lasts

  if (step == counter) {
    wizardSection[counter].style.display = 'none';
    wizardSection[counter - 1].style.display = 'block';
  }

  counter--;
  progressWidth -= progressStepLength;

  //set zero progress in first step of quiz, because in fact first step is start page
  if (counter <= 1) {
    progressWidth = 0;
  }

  prev.style.display = 'block';

  progress.style.width = `${progressWidth}%`;
  wizardPercent.innerHTML = `${progressWidth}%`;

  if (counter == 0) {
    prev.style.display = 'none';
    progressBar.style.display = 'none';
    next.innerHTML = 'Start!';
  } else {
    prev.style.display = 'block';
  }

});


//Submit form (use jQuery)

$(function() {
  var form = $('#wizardForm'),
    formMessages = $('#formMessages');

  $(form).on('change', function(ev) {
    if (ev.target.tagName == 'INPUT' && ev.target.getAttribute('type') == 'radio') {
      next.dispatchEvent(new Event('click', {
        bubbles: true
      }));
    }
  });

  $(form).submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    formData = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log('ajax ok ');
        },
        error: function(data) {
          console.log('ajax error ');
        }
      })
      .done(function(response) {
        $(formMessages).toggleClass('cuccess');
        $(formMessages).css('display', 'block');
        $(formMessages).text(response);
        $('#wizardForm input').val('');
        console.log(formData);
        console.log(result);
        document.location.href = 'http://mkozlov.com/thanks.html';
      })
      .fail(function(data) {
        $(formMessages).toggleClass('error');
        // $(formMessages).addClass('error');
        $(formMessages).css('display', 'block');
        $(formMessages).text('Упс! Сообщение не удалось отправить');
        console.log(formData);
      });
  });

  $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $(formMessages).css('display', 'block');
    $('#ajaxLoader').css('display', 'block');
    console.log('ajax-start');
  })

});
```

```css
/* ==========Base styles: opinionated defaults=========== */

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
}

input {
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: outset;
  border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form-block {
  text-align: center;
  width: 45%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
}

.form-block-info {
  text-align: center;
}

.result-text {
  text-align: center;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
}


/*============= Variables ================== */

 :root {
  --accent: #f10315;
  --accent2: #b1020f;
  --text: #333;
}


/*============= Author's custom styles================== */

.start-section {
  text-align: center;
}

.wizard-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: var(--text);
  box-shadow: 1px 6px 22px rgba(49, 49, 49, .2);
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.wizard ul {
  list-style: none
}


/*Wizard-form*/

.wizard-section h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.wizard input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.wizard input {
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.wizard-content-block {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
  /*display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;*/
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: distribute;
  align-content: space-around;
}

.answer-variants {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 45%;
  flex: 45%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(217, 216, 230, .55);
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 1.7px 5.8px 21px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
  border: 1px solid rgba(217, 216, 230, .55);
  padding: .8rem 1rem;
}

.wizard-content-block label {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.wizard-content-block label span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  min-width: 15px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.wizard-content-block label span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 60%;
  width: 60%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-55%) translateY(-48%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.wizard-content-block label span:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 12px rgba(49, 49, 49, .4);
}

.wizard-content-block label input[type=radio]:checked+span {
  border: 2px solid #f10315;
}

.wizard-content-block label input[type=radio]:checked+span:before {
  background-color: #f10315;
}

.ajax-loader {
  display: none;
  margin: 5px auto;
}

.wizard .wpcf7-not-valid-tip {
  margin: 5px auto;
}

.input-result {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 22px !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* PROGRESS LINE */

.progress-bar {
  display: none;
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px auto 40px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.progress-bar>span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: var(--accent);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, var(--accent), var(--accent2));
}

.wizard-percent {
  position: absolute;
  /*right: -20px;*/
  top: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: var(--accent);
  width: 100px;
}


/* BUTTONS */

.wizard button.button-back {
  display: none;
  color: #363636;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 13px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .13);
}

.wizard .actions {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.wizard .button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #f10315;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all.3s;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  ;
  line-height: 1.5;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 13px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .13);
}

.wizard .button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wizard .button:hover {
  background-color: #f10315;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 13px rgba(49, 49, 49, .3);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.final-section .submit-btn {
  width: auto;
}

.form-messages {
  display: none;
  color: var(--accent2);
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid var(--accent);
}

.cuccess {}

.error {
  border: 2px solid red;
}


/* ============= Helper classes=============== */

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}


/*
* Hide only visually, but have it available for screen readers:
*/

.visuallyhidden {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* 1 */
}


/*
* Hide visually and from screen readers, but maintain layout
*/

.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}


/* ====================MEDIA==================== */

@media (max-width: 992px) {}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .wizard-content-block {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .wizard .button {
    width: 48%;
  }
  .final-section .submit-btn {
    width: 100%;
  }
  input {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .wizard-wrapper {
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .form-block {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="wizard-wrapper">
    <form id="wizardForm" action="send.php">
      <div class="wizard">
        <div class="progress-bar" id="progressBar">
          <span style="width: 0px;">
            <span class="wizard-percent" id="wizardPercent">0%</span>
          </span>
        </div>

        <!-- Start section -->
        <section class="wizard-section start-section" data-step="0" style="display: block;">
          <h2>Тест: Рейтинг Невесты</h2>
          <p>Если честно и объективно оцените себя по 24 параметрам, то сможете оценить свои реальные шансы выйти за муж за достойного, обеспеченного мужчину</p>
          <div class="wizard-content-block">

          </div>
        </section>

        <!-- Quiz sections -->
        <section class="wizard-section" data-step="1" style="display: none;">
          <h3>Сколько вам лет?</h3>
          <div class="wizard-content-block">
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="10">
                <span></span>
                18 - 20 лет
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="9">
                <span></span>
                21 - 22 года
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="8">
                <span></span>
                23 - 24 года
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="7">
                <span></span>
                25 - 26 лет
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="6">
                <span></span>
                27 - 29 лет
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="5">
                <span></span>
                30 - 32 года
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="4">
                <span></span>
                33 - 35 лет
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="3">
                <span></span>
                36 - 39 лет
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="2">
                <span></span>
                40 - 45 лет
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="1">
                <span></span>
                старше 45 лет
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

        <section class="wizard-section" data-step="2" style="display: none;">
          <h3>Оцените свою внешность</h3>
          <div class="wizard-content-block">
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="face" value="10">
                <span></span>
                Мисс Вселенная
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="face" value="9">
                <span></span>
                Топ модель Западного уровня
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="face" value="8">
                <span></span>
                Топ модель России
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="face" value="7">
                <span></span>
                Красивая
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="face" value="6">
                <span></span>
                Симпатичная
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="face" value="5">
                <span></span>
                Миловидная
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="face" value="4">
                <span></span>
                Неприметная
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="face" value="3">
                <span></span>
                Легкие недостатки
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="face" value="2">
                <span></span>
                Заметные недостатки
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-variants">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="face" value="1">
                <span></span>
                Зато умная
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Result sections -->
        <section class="wizard-section final-section" data-step="25" style="display: none;">
          <div class="wizard-content-block">
            <h3 class="text-center result-text">Ваши рейтинг невесты:
              <input type="text" class="input-result text-center" id="result" name="result" value=""></h3>
            <h3 class="text-center form-info">Хотите узнать, что эта цифра значит и как повысить свои шансы выйти удачно замуж? </h3>
            <div class="form-block">
              <div class="form-group">
                <p class="text-center form-block-info">Регистрируйтесь на бесплатный вебинар, на котором вы узнаете все ответы.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="Ваше имя" id="name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="tel" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Номер телефона" id="phone">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Ваш e-mail" id="email" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="button submit-btn" id="wizardSubmit">Принять участие</button>
              </div>
              <div class="form-messages" id="formMessages">
                <div class="ajax-loader" id="ajaxLoader">
                  <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.0" width="64px" height="64px" viewBox="0 0 128 128" xml:space="preserve">
                    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#FFFFFF" />
                    <g>
                      <circle cx="16" cy="64" r="16" fill="#fdba00" fill-opacity="1" />
                      <circle cx="16" cy="64" r="14.344" fill="#fdba00" fill-opacity="1" transform="rotate(45 64 64)" />
                      <circle cx="16" cy="64" r="12.531" fill="#fdba00" fill-opacity="1" transform="rotate(90 64 64)" />
                      <circle cx="16" cy="64" r="10.75" fill="#fdba00" fill-opacity="1" transform="rotate(135 64 64)" />
                      <circle cx="16" cy="64" r="10.063" fill="#fdba00" fill-opacity="1" transform="rotate(180 64 64)" />
                      <circle cx="16" cy="64" r="8.063" fill="#fdba00" fill-opacity="1" transform="rotate(225 64 64)" />
                      <circle cx="16" cy="64" r="6.438" fill="#fdba00" fill-opacity="1" transform="rotate(270 64 64)" />
                      <circle cx="16" cy="64" r="5.375" fill="#fdba00" fill-opacity="1" transform="rotate(315 64 64)" />
                      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 64 64;315 64 64;270 64 64;225 64 64;180 64 64;135 64 64;90 64 64;45 64 64"
                        calcMode="discrete" dur="720ms" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform>
                    </g>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

        <!-- Step buttons -->
        <div class="actions">
          <button class="button button-back" href="#progressBar" id="back">Назад</button>
          <button class="button button-next" href="#progressBar" id="next">Далее</button>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="response display-none"></div>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: не совсем понял, какой именно фрагмент кода? Попробовал так, как вы предложили, не заработало.

Comment: прошу прощения, исправил

Comment: супер, благодарю. Может еще подскажете, как сделать, чтобы до отображения следующего шага, checkbox все-таки отмечался, а после чего уже происходил переход?

Comment: @ИльяТроян, попробуйте вызывать событие клик через setTimeout. То есть событие будет происходить спустя N мс.